# IONIC 3 - IOS: [Error] Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to debug ionic app in mac:

```
$ ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --debug
```

In one of the requests of API SERVER(.NET) I get the error:

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

[image]

```js
login(login: LoginModel | null): Observable<LoginInfo | null> {
  let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/API/Login/Login";
  url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

  const content_ = JSON.stringify(login);

  let options_ : any = {
    body: content_,
    observe: "response",
    responseType: "blob",
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json", 
      "Accept": "application/json"
    })
  };

  return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).flatMap((response_ : any) => {
    return this.processLogin(response_);
  }).catch((response_: any) => {
    if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
      try {
        return this.processLogin(<any>response_);
      } catch (e) {
        return <Observable<LoginInfo | null>><any>Observable.throw(e);
      }
    } else
      return <Observable<LoginInfo | null>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
   });
 }
```

Comment: You need to verify in your server side whether CORS is setup correctly.  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is set in server side

Comment: @SurajRao in server side it set. It response me error if i put the parameter - class json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

So the correctly it to set `Access-Control-Allow-...` in server.

- Safari does not allow `*` like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
```

**Correct setting is**:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

Comment: is there any documentation around this behavior for mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You can set some configs in your `express.js` server.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://yourdomain.com',
  ];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```